# PsychToolBox: Error passing input from GUI to simple Pavlovian script

Tags: psych, psychtoolbox

I have a GUI created from GUIDE (PITGUI.m) that is supposed to pass some simple input from the GUI to a Pavlovian script (PITtask.m) as a structure. When running it I'm receiving the following error:

```
Error: File: PITtask.m Line: 61 Column: 113
Invalid expression. When calling a function or indexing a variable,         use parentheses. Otherwise, check for
mismatched delimiters.[enter link description here][1]
Error in PITGUI>RunExp_Callback (line 271)
PITtask(handles);

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)
    feval(varargin{:});

Error in PITGUI (line 42)
gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in
     matlab.graphics.internal.figfile.FigFile/read>@(hObject,eventdata)PITGUI('R.  unExp_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
```

Error using uiwait (line 81)
   Error while evaluating DestroyedObject Callback.

I have put the links for the GUI and Pavlovian scripts as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Lauren

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8jspl7l233w62ek/PITGUI.m?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/g3pabwtqs06g4xj/PITtask.m?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

To run your code, you would also need to post 'PITGUI.fig'. But, the error message you posted is triggered on line 61 of 'PITtask.m'. On line 61, it looks like you have command that spans multiple lines, but you haven't used ellipses (...) to indicate a multi-line command

Try changing:

```
fprintf(outfile, '%i %s %s %i %i %s \n', InputDataStruct.subn, InputDataStruct.subname, InputDataStruct.subsex, 
InputDataStruct.subage, InputDataStruct.nblocks, InputDataStruct.subnote);
```

To:

```
fprintf(outfile, '%i %s %s %i %i %s \n', InputDataStruct.subn, InputDataStruct.subname, InputDataStruct.subsex,... 
InputDataStruct.subage, InputDataStruct.nblocks, InputDataStruct.subnote);
```